# Apache Nifi Fails to start

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I am trying to install and start apache Nifi in order to access the browser UI on my Windows system.

When I download and extract the latest version of NiFi, after running the run-nifi bat file I get the following error:

> 2023-01-12 11:20:51,597 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Generating Self-Signed Certificate: Expires on 2023-03-13
> 2023-01-12 11:20:53,772 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Generated Self-Signed Certificate SHA-256: 5E63D14A2D5640344E58C1EB5C005F9753734DF7657D08D200A66B6CE8F0AF33
> 2023-01-12 11:20:53,787 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Starting Apache NiFi...
> 2023-01-12 11:20:53,787 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Working Directory: C:\NIFI-1~1.0
> 2023-01-12 11:20:53,787 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Command: C:\Program Files\Java\zulu8.46.0.19-ca-jdk8.0.252-win_x64\bin\java.exe -classpath C:\NIFI-1~1.0.\conf;C:\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.36.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\jetty-schemas-5.2.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.36.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.36.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\logback-classic-1.2.11.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\logback-core-1.2.11.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\nifi-api-1.18.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\nifi-framework-api-1.18.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\nifi-nar-utils-1.18.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\nifi-properties-1.18.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\nifi-property-utils-1.18.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\nifi-runtime-1.18.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\nifi-server-api-1.18.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\nifi-stateless-api-1.18.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\nifi-stateless-bootstrap-1.18.0.jar;C:\NIFI-1~1.0.\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true -Xmx512m -Xms512m -Dcurator-log-only-first-connection-issue-as-error-level=true -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -Dzookeeper.admin.enableServer=false -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=sun.net.www.protocol -Dnifi.properties.file.path=C:\NIFI-1~1.0.\conf\nifi.properties -Dnifi.bootstrap.listen.port=49551 -Dapp=NiFi -Dorg.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir=C:\NIFI-1~1.0\bin..\logs org.apache.nifi.NiFi
> 2023-01-12 11:20:53,787 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to determine Process ID from [java.lang.ProcessImpl]: java.lang.Process.pid()
> 2023-01-12 11:20:53,787 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Launched Apache NiFi but could not determined the Process ID

I am currently running java zulu8.46.0.19-ca-jdk8.0.252-win_x64

Here is the download I used:
https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua?path=/nifi/1.19.1/nifi-1.19.1-bin.zip

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: do you see any errors in nifi log files?